# ManToGif code: how can I avoid time-reversal in the animated GIF?

Tags: export, image, gif-format

`ManToGif` is a very useful function to create smooth animated GIF from a`Manipulate` expression.

```
ManToGif[man_, name_String, step_Integer] := 
  Export[
   name <> ".gif", 
   Import[
     Export[
       name <> 
         Which[
           $OperatingSystem == "MacOSX", ".mov", 
           $OperatingSystem == "Windows", ".avi"], 
        man], 
     "ImageList"][[1 ;; -1 ;; step]]];
```

The created animated GIF runs forward and them runs backward.

Unfortunately, I don't understand details of `ManToGif`, so I don't know how to create a GIF that only runs forward. Do you know how to specify it?

Comment: Please add a link to the original `ManToGif`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Here may be the original of the function: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994